# Is the tritone (diminished fifth) used in alarm sirens?

Tags: intervals, consonance-and-dissonance

I have read claims that the tritone, due to its dissonant nature, is used for things like police, ambulance, rocket or tornado sirens. I am a beginner music theory learner and would not be able to identify it with certainty just by listening to it.

If this is indeed true, I am looking for an answer with at least one example of an alarm siren anywhere in the world which uses this interval.

Comment: Warning: the stereotypical police/ambulance siren I can hear in my head stays on a **single note** for a significant period of time, then smoothly drops in pitch.

Comment: You mean the 'woo-woo' sirens or the old 'nee-nar'? The old nee-nars used to not have a fixed interval - once made fun of by Griff Rhys Jones having several police cars drive into shot, one at a time, making up the opening verse line of "Somewhere Over the Rainbow"… which sadly i can't find on youtube. The French sirens in old Inspector Clouseau movies were also 'odd' to an English ear, being different again.

Comment: @Tetsujin Any kind of siren which makes use of the tritone

Comment: French sirens tend to be P5, UK tend to be m3.

Comment: It's a nice idea, although a lot of UK ordinary double car horns seem to be tuned to m3 as well (not alternating, obviously!)

Comment: I have not been able to find any reference for civil defense or emergency sirens.  Related: (US) railroad locomotive airhorns are sometimes tuned to a chord (e.g. diminished) that includes a tritone.  The [Nathan P5a](http://atsf.railfan.net/airhorns/p5a.html) is what I hear on the Metra commuter locomotives here in Chicago.

Comment: @Tim - the G R Jones one was m3, then M2 with the same top note, then he ran into shot in police uniform to sing 'behind me' on F. [E♭,C, E♭,C, E♭,C, E♭,C, E♭,D♭, E♭,D♭, E♭,D♭, E♭,D♭, 'behind me']. Oh, how we laughed…. actually it worked well because you just didn't see it coming.

Comment: Here's a great video on various tritone myths: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MhwGnq4N9o

Comment: At risk of being overly critical, is this a transcription question?

Comment: @ToddWilcox I'm not sure what you mean. The [transcription] tag has the following description: "Creating notation for a piece of music based on a performance recording." It does not seem related.

Comment: I seem to recall European sirens sounding tritone-ish.  I've never heard it in the US though.

Comment: @Tim the classic French police siren is a perfect fourth, not a perfect fifth.  This could easily be mistaken for a tritone because, as a friend once noted, they seem to be out of tune with _themselves._  In fact, they are out of tune with _their reflections,_ which have a different Doppler shift.  But my favorite French Doppler shift story is from my first ride on a TGV, when a train sounded its horn as we passed, and the shift created an interval of a major sixth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

I think train horns is a good place to look, because lots of different tunings have been used. I've always associated train horns with some kind of diminished harmony. I thought a half-diminished chord was common, but apparently it's a fully diminished seventh chord that some train horns have. At any rate diminished harmonies are those with a diminished fifth, one of the interval spellings of a tritone.

Here is a typically obsessive rail fan page...

http://atsf.railfan.net/airhorns/

It lists lots of horns with incredible detail, including factory tuning of the "chimes" (the horns.)

One of the horns listed...

http://atsf.railfan.net/airhorns/s3l.html

...has this tuning

> Factory tuning is: 255, 311, and 440 Hz (approximately C, D#, A)

`D# A` is the tritone. Sound clips are available on the page. Apparently this was a very common train horn in the US, so it seems a particularly good example.

This one...

http://atsf.railfan.net/airhorns/s5t.html

...is interesting too, because it contains tones of both diminished and half-diminished seventh chords.

Comment: Beat me to it.  I was linking to 5-chime in the comments!